# I want to rearrange table data basis of column and rows

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I have database table like this:

```
col1 col2 
1   data1
1   data2
1   data3
2   data4
2   data5
2   data6
3   data7
3   data8
3   data9
```

(data of rows which has col1 value=1,will be used as column name);
I need to convert this into following format:

```
col1 data1  data2  data3
2    data4  data5  data6
3    data7  data8  data9
4    data10 data11 data12
```

I have tried `pivot` function and also tried manually transformation using procedure and functions, but nothing has worked me so far.

Edit: I am using oracle. Earlier I tagged mysql by mistake.

Comment: You have mistakenly tagged two different DBMS, Oracle and MySQL. Which of the two are you using? Then, it's always exactly three rows per col1 value? Does the order matter or is 2|data6|data4|data5 okay with you?

Comment: Display issues are usually dealt with in your app or Website, not in SQL. If you really want to do this in SQL, window functions would be helpful. Oracle has featured them for a long time, but MySQL only since version 8. So, in case you are using MySQL: which version are you using?

Comment: DBMS table is not a spreadsheet where you may put any value in any cell. DBMS result set structure is defined by the statement after the parsing is done. So to have dynamic column names (that depend on data) you need a dynamic SQL

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, you can use `ROW_NUMBER` and then `PIVOT`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY col1 ORDER BY col2) AS rn
  FROM   table_name t
)
PIVOT (
  MAX(col2) FOR rn IN (1 AS col2_1, 2 As col2_2, 3 AS col2_3)
);
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (col1, col2) AS
SELECT CEIL(LEVEL/3), 'data' || LEVEL FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 9;
```

Outputs:

> | COL1 | COL2_1 | COL2_2 | COL2_3 |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | data1 | data2 | data3 |
> | 2 | data4 | data5 | data6 |
> | 3 | data7 | data8 | data9 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f0975edf6a6ec9d8172fbd2ebaac7da5)*

Comment: "...data of rows which has col1 value=1,will be used as column name". Not a relational requirement, but it was in the question

Comment: @astentx I missed that bit .... the OP can only do that with dynamic SQL; its not possible with a normal `PIVOT` as it is not possible to dynamically rename columns.